# Getting the size of a SystemVerilog macro range

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a code with a number of different signals whose width is defined by macro ranges like this:

```
`define MY_RANGE_1 8:2
`define MY_RANGE_2 12:0
`define MY_RANGE_3 5:0
```

I want to obtain the widths of those signals in order to later use them in new signal definitions. Such a feature should return 7 for MY_RANGE_1, then for MY_RANGE_2 it should return 13, and for MY_RANGE_3 it should return 6. Of course, there are array size methods like `$size(MY_FEATURE_1)`, but they won't be appropriate for my purposes because they don't return a constant value (so you can't define new signal ranges through them). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How is `MY_FEATURE_1` defined. You should be able to use $bits or $size in a constant expression as long as there are no dynamically sized arrays involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text macros in verilog are just fragments of text and have no syntactic meaning. Therefore, there is no way to extract range info from the macro itself. However, in *System* verilog there is the predefine function *$bits" which returns bit width of a declared variable or a type. It can be used in subsequent variable declarations as well. For example,

```
`define MY_RANGE_1 8:2
module top;
 reg[`MY_RANGE_1] myvar;
 reg [$bits(myvar) - 1: 0] myvar1;
  
 initial begin
    $display("type: %0d", $bits(reg[`MY_RANGE_1]));
    $display("var:  %0d", $bits(myvar));
    $display("var1: %0d", $bits(myvar1));
 end
endmodule // top
```

The result of *$bits* is `7` in all cases.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I was looking for.